# Laravel Pusher private channel not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, pusher

When i use public channel the pusher sends data successfully. But as soon as i use private channel with correct route in channels.php file it doesn't work.

```
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
          return ['test-channel'];

    }

When i use **return new PrivateChannel('test-channel');** in broadcastOn() method it won't work. This is my channels.api file code:

    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use App\Models\Message;
use Auth;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('test-channel', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

This is where i am using jquery to load pusher message.

```
function pushnote()
```

{
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

```
var pusher = new Pusher('{{env("MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY")}}', {
    cluster: '{{env("PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER")}}',
    encrypted: true,

});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\NewMessage', function(data) {

    // console.log(data.message.content);
    // alert(data.message.content);
    // alert(data);
    alert('success');
    // getLatestMessage(data.message.content);
    getLatestMessage(data);
});
}
```

I want pusher functionality in my chat application. Please someone help. You can contact me personally.

Comment: What 'Doesn't work'? The server sending events or the client? 
Does the client subscribe the channel ok?

Comment: It doesn't subscribe to the private channel. But it debugs to the pusher console.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means - can you share what is found in the pusher console?

Comment: I get this response in pusher debug console.

Comment: Channel: private-test-channel, Event: App\Events\NewMessage with this message in json

Comment: {
  "message": {
    "id": 131,
    "from_user": 2,
    "to_user": 3,
    "content": "Hi"
  }
}

Comment: It seems your client is not subscribing correctly if you are not seeing `Subscribe` or `Connected` events. You mention that publlic channels work, the primary difference between public and private channels is authentication: you should check that authentication is correctly set up for your app. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Comment: Need better explaination. Give a code example someone.

Answer (score 0):

In the pusher documentation for private channels the name must be prefixed with private- like

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-test-channel');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\NewMessage', function(data) {
```

You can find document [here](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/private-channels)

Comment: Still not working even using private prefix.

Comment: Even though its debugging to console but not binding or subscribing.

Comment: Have you changed also in channels.php ?

Comment: Nope its same as earlier.